# unwrapping nested promises in JS

Tags: javascript, promise

Relatively simple task:

Make repeated REST requests for data and concatenate parts of each response into a single list for processing. I'm struggling to wrap my head around the js async model and wondering if this just isn't the appropriate task? Bottom line is -- what is the idiomatic way of dealing with a situation like below?

```
const https = require('https');

function post(body, path, token = null) {
    const data = JSON.stringify(body);
    const headers = {
        accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': data.length,
        'Authorization': token,
    }
    const options = {
        hostname: 'api.sensorpush.com',
        port: 443,
        path: path,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let body = Buffer.alloc(0)
        const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
            res.on('data', (d) => {
                body = Buffer.concat([body, d])
            })
            res.on('end', () => {
                if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
                    reject(new Error(`Got status code ${res.statusCode}`))
                }
                try {
                    return resolve(JSON.parse(body.toString()))
                } catch (e) {
                    reject(e)
                }
            })
        })
        req.on('error', (err) => reject(err))
        req.write(data)
        req.end()
    })
}

async function get_data(time) {
    const auth_body = {
        email: usrname,
        password: pw,
    }
    const auth_path = '/api/v1/oauth/authorize'
    let { authorization } = await post(auth_body, auth_path)
    const tok_body = {
        "authorization": authorization
    }
    const tok_path = '/api/v1/oauth/accesstoken'
    let { accesstoken } = await post(tok_body, tok_path)

    endTime = new Date(time)
    startTime = new Date(time.setDate(time.getDate() - 1))

    let s1 = []
    let s2 = []
    while (startTime < endTime) {
        console.log(startTime)
        data_body = {
            "startTime": startTime.toISOString(),
        }
        data_path = '/api/v1/samples'
        data = await post(data_body, data_path, accesstoken)
        startTime = new Date(data['last_time'])
        s1 = s1.concat(data['sensors']['305349.3638533352933283797'])
        s2 = s2.concat(data['sensors']['305349.3638533352933283797'])
    }
    return s1, s2
}
```

When I call `get_data()` I'm returned something like this:

```
> data
Promise {
  {
    last_time: '2021-02-08T06:25:55.000Z',
    sensors: {
      'SENSORID': [Array],
      'SENSORID': [Array]
    },
    truncated: false,
    status: 'OK',
    total_samples: 25,
    total_sensors: 2
  }
}
```

But I don't know how to actually USE the values here outside of executing some really long and verbose chain of `then(...)`'s. If I say `data.then((o) => o['sensors']` now I have

```
> s
Promise {
  {
    'SENSORID': [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object]
    ],
    'SENSORID': [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object]
    ]
  }
}
```

And it goes on and on...

Comment: Can you be bit more clear? I am having hard time understanding your statement.

Comment: The idiomatic way to deal with Promise objects created inside a loop as you have done, is to push them into an array of Promises and then use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to resolve them all at once or deal with the rejection.

Comment: Alternatively, is there a reason you didn't `await` the call to `post` inside the loop? Can you explain the `return` inside the loop (a code smell).

Comment: the code wasn't quite right.. apologies. I've updated it to reflect what I'm after. Think this should work now but if you have any suggestions I'd be more than happy to hear them.

Comment: "*But I don't know how to actually USE the values here outside of executing some really long and verbose chain of `then(...)`*" - just like you already did with the promises returned by `post` inside `get_data`: you `await` them instead of chaining `then`s!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are making many API calls, I would suggest you to use `Promise.all()` instead of using `data = await post(data_body, data_path, accesstoken)` which will trigger the next request only after completing the first. Modifying your code.

```
async function get_data(time) {
    const auth_body = {
        email: 'gardnerlab@icloud.com',
        password: 'kccanary',
    }
    const auth_path = '/api/v1/oauth/authorize'
    let {
        authorization
    } = await post(auth_body, auth_path)
    const tok_body = {
        "authorization": authorization
    }
    const tok_path = '/api/v1/oauth/accesstoken'
    let {
        accesstoken
    } = await post(tok_body, tok_path)

    endTime = new Date(time)
    startTime = new Date(time.setDate(time.getDate() - 1))
    const promiseRequests = []
    while (startTime < endTime) {

        data_body = {
            "startTime": startTime.toISOString(),
        }
        data_path = '/api/v1/samples'
        promiseRequests.push(post(data_body, data_path, accesstoken));
    }
    Promise.all(promiseRequests).then(responseArr => {
       responseArr.forEach(response => console.log(response.sensors));
    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

Comment: updated code above. thing is I need to resolve them sequentially because the loop breaks subject to a value returned in the response.

Comment: In that case use [Promise.allSettled()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) - you can then isolate resolved vs. rejected in the output. @curious_coder - perhaps change answer to reflect.